Do helicopters have to pay landing fee?
Is there a landing fee for helicopters?
I ask because since they usually don't use the runway hence doesn't cause maintenance costs for the airport I would imagine they have at least a different fee to pay if they have to pay?
Is that how it works?

They may not use the runway, but they still use airport infrastructure, handling, ATC and so on

In the UK landing fees are pretty much ubiquitous at all airfields, from large commercial airfields down to small GA airfields. Typically the fees for helicopters are at least as much as fixed wing aircraft and often times higher.
The most popular GA airfield in the UK publishes their charges and as you can see from that page they charge as much for a small helicopter (such as a R22) as for a light 4 seater (PA28).
Another airfield I know very well, which is very close to London and often used for helicopter traffic to central London, the Grand Prix and other such events visited by those fortunate enough to use helicopter transport also publish their charges and for that airfield the charges are much higher for helicopter landing fees ranging from £25 up to £350.
So yes, helicopters absolutely pay landing fees where it is the standard practice to do so. They may not use the runways, but they often have a dedicated heli-apron, dedicated ground crew (helicopters cant maneuver themselves into hangars/parking, and often need specialist equipment and handling), dedicated fuel bowsers (again, often unable to taxy themselves to fuel). All of this costs money and time, and in the UK at least, is funded in part by landing fees.

I won't attempt to answer for whatever country you are in but I think we can assume that my situation is somewhat similar to yours too.
My nearest airport is Mumbai Intl. and according to this Airport Charges file I found, that there IS a charge for all types of aircraft. Usually, helicopters land at the smaller airport that is right next to the international one but the charges are similar I believe.
The documents I've seen show that they don't look at your runway usage, they just see whether you're on the airport grounds, or not.
For Mumbai Intl. in the FY2013-14 file it's mentioned that

A minimum fee of Rs. 16,341 and Rs. 21,788 shall be charged per single
domestic and international landing respectively for all types of aircraft/
helicopter flights, including but not limited to domestic landing, international
landing and general aviation landing.

There's more charges based on your aircraft weight too.
So that's there and there's more charges that're there in that file. It's very outdated but the question is more yes or no so I think this file is perfectly fine.
So for the question, do they have a different fee; mostly no, but by weight, passenger capacity, and other factors, their fees will be lowered significantly or at least slightly
Currency Conversions:

circa 2013, ₹1 = $0.018

current rate as of writing this, ₹1 = $0.012



ok, I was thinking a Cessna 172 and a Robinson R44 both have similar weight and passenger capacity, but the helicopter doesn't use the runway still has to pay the same.... just thinking....

@Gabe yes, but landing fees encompasses a lot of things other than simply runway utilization.

yeah, that's a fair way to put it.

In the US, in most public airports, there is no landing fee. For General Aviation, airports are financed via fuel surcharges, which are can be anything between one dollar to five dollars per gallon, from my observations. In the US, helicopters can land on taxiways or have dedicated landing spots. In the US, you can also land a helicopter anywhere, where the landowner allows it. One guy in my neighborhood lands his on an empty lot, in a suburban neighborhood with otherwise high density.
